# Truncating the range of Total Point in a Nomogram

Tags: r, survival-analysis

I have created a nomogram in R using the `nomogram` function from the `rms` package but, due to the "Total Points" default range being from 0 - maximum possible value it is very difficult to see and thus interpret the predicted probabilities.

[image]

I would like to be able to truncate the "Total Points" to range from 250-350 but I really don't know how to do this.

There is an argument in the `nomogram` function called `total.fun` in which you can specify a function regarding the total points but I don't know how I could implement what I am trying to achieve in there or if it is even possible.

My data is confidential so I cannot share it but the `lung` sample dataset from the `survival` package is similar in natural (i.e. for survival analysis) and I based my code off the [Zhang and Kattan "Nomogram for survival data" example](https://atm.amegroups.com/article/view/14736/html).

```
## Distribution summaries of predictors
ddist <- datadist(clean_df)
## Setting dimensions to data distribution
options(datadist = 'ddist')

# Model
mod.cox <- cph(Surv(time, status) ~ 
             stage + grade + psa + age + family_history +
             cd14 + igfbp3 + apoaii + gc_globulin + zag + pedf + vegfd,
           data = clean_df, surv = TRUE)

## Estimates of Survival function
surv.cox <- Survival(mod.cox)

## Cox Nomogram
### 3-,5-yr Survival Probabilities
nom.cox <- nomogram(mod.cox,
                    fun = list(function(x) surv.cox(36, x),function(x) surv.cox(60, x)),
                    funlabel = c("3-Yr Sur. Prob.",
                                 "5-Yr Sur. Prob."),
                    lp = FALSE,
                    vnames=c("labels","names"))
```

Comment: Your model doesn’t appear to discriminate very well. It appears that you may have failed at some step. I would suggest going back and figure out if you made an error in model construction.

Comment: @IRTFM I am aware the model does not appear to discriminate well, but for the data I am working with this is quite an accurate representation of the true survival probabilities. Your response also does not answer my question regarding the truncation of the total points.

Comment: I don't think you understand how questions are expected to be posed on SO. This is a coding site, so asking from modifications of code to solve problems requires that data be included. In cases of followup for prostate cancer such as your models appear to be examining, it would be very unusual to find a situation where stage and grade were not much more discriminatory in survival outcomes. Perhaps you have other information that is not being shared. I don't see how specific advice can be given without data.

Comment: Note: Questions get closed for lack of data. Here's the canned text that people can use to justify a close vote: `Needs debugging details :::
The question should be updated to include desired behavior, a specific problem or error, and the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem.`  We cannot reproduce your problem without data. I'm not voting because I hope you present some data.